# Electron: print a React component to thermal printer

Tags: reactjs, printing, electron, driver, point-of-sale

I am attemting to print a react component that simulates a receipt to a physical thermal printer. I already have the driver installed and it prints the react component from the "browser" window, but it does not do this with high quality.

I have used the npm package electron-pos-printer with no luck. Any ideas?

I tried various libraries with various degrees of success, but all got me insufficient quality when printing. Somewhere the quality is breaking down when passing the html/jsx to the window printer function that is eventually called in all the packages I have inspected and I have also used it manually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please expand on what you have tried and [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also, what is "insufficient quality" – what would you consider "sufficient"? Ideally, you'd also show us how the component you're trying to print is styled, because some elements are, by default, disabled while printing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.